# How to turn off elasticsearch modules during startup?

Tags: elasticsearch, optimization

During elasticsearch startup I need to wait about 15 seconds before starting using it. In logs I can see many modules loaded. I think that part of it can be disabled, e.g. `repository-gcs`, `kibana` or `ingest-geoip`. How can I disable part of them?

Example output (I have trimmed output for better readability):

```
21:39:42.015Z", "message":"loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]", 
21:39:42.015Z", "message":"loaded module [analysis-common]", 
21:39:42.015Z", "message":"loaded module [constant-keyword]", 
21:39:42.016Z", "message":"loaded module [data-streams]", 
21:39:42.016Z", "message":"loaded module [frozen-indices]", 
21:39:42.016Z", "message":"loaded module [ingest-attachment]", 
21:39:42.016Z", "message":"loaded module [ingest-common]", 
21:39:42.017Z", "message":"loaded module [ingest-geoip]", 
21:39:42.017Z", "message":"loaded module [ingest-user-agent]", 
21:39:42.017Z", "message":"loaded module [kibana]", 
21:39:42.017Z", "message":"loaded module [lang-expression]", 
21:39:42.018Z", "message":"loaded module [lang-mustache]", 
21:39:42.018Z", "message":"loaded module [lang-painless]", 
21:39:42.018Z", "message":"loaded module [legacy-geo]", 
21:39:42.018Z", "message":"loaded module [mapper-extras]", 
21:39:42.019Z", "message":"loaded module [mapper-version]", 
21:39:42.019Z", "message":"loaded module [old-lucene-versions]", 
21:39:42.019Z", "message":"loaded module [parent-join]", 
21:39:42.019Z", "message":"loaded module [percolator]", 
21:39:42.020Z", "message":"loaded module [rank-eval]", 
21:39:42.020Z", "message":"loaded module [reindex]", 
21:39:42.020Z", "message":"loaded module [repositories-metering-api]", 
21:39:42.020Z", "message":"loaded module [repository-azure]", 
21:39:42.020Z", "message":"loaded module [repository-encrypted]", 
21:39:42.021Z", "message":"loaded module [repository-gcs]", 
21:39:42.021Z", "message":"loaded module [repository-s3]", 
21:39:42.021Z", "message":"loaded module [repository-url]", 
21:39:42.021Z", "message":"loaded module [runtime-fields-common]", 
21:39:42.021Z", "message":"loaded module [search-business-rules]", 
21:39:42.022Z", "message":"loaded module [searchable-snapshots]", 
21:39:42.022Z", "message":"loaded module [snapshot-based-recoveries]", 
21:39:42.022Z", "message":"loaded module [snapshot-repo-test-kit]", 
21:39:42.022Z", "message":"loaded module [spatial]", 
21:39:42.022Z", "message":"loaded module [transform]", 
21:39:42.022Z", "message":"loaded module [transport-netty4]", 
21:39:42.023Z", "message":"loaded module [unsigned-long]", 
21:39:42.023Z", "message":"loaded module [vector-tile]", 
21:39:42.023Z", "message":"loaded module [wildcard]", 
21:39:42.023Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-aggregate-metric]", 
21:39:42.023Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-analytics]", 
21:39:42.023Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-async]", 
21:39:42.024Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-async-search]", 
21:39:42.024Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-autoscaling]", 
21:39:42.024Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-ccr]", 
21:39:42.025Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-core]", 
21:39:42.025Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]", 
21:39:42.025Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-enrich]", 
21:39:42.025Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-eql]", 
21:39:42.025Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-fleet]", 
21:39:42.025Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-graph]", 
21:39:42.026Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-identity-provider]", 
21:39:42.026Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-ilm]", 
21:39:42.026Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-logstash]", 
21:39:42.026Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-ml]", 
21:39:42.026Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]", 
21:39:42.027Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-ql]", 
21:39:42.027Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-rollup]", 
21:39:42.027Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-security]", 
21:39:42.027Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-shutdown]", 
21:39:42.027Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-sql]", 
21:39:42.028Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-stack]", 
21:39:42.028Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-text-structure]", 
21:39:42.028Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-voting-only-node]", 
21:39:42.028Z", "message":"loaded module [x-pack-watcher]",
```

Comment: As you can see by the timestamps, it takes 13 ms to load them all...

Comment: @Val I was curious about their influence on total startup time, e.g. "Let's turn off `searchable-snapshots` and see it is responsible for much of the startup time"

Answer (score 2):

tldr - you can't as they are all core parts of Elasticsearch. they have been split out into modules to allow easier development, rather than to be switched on or off at will

(as Val mentions above, they take 13ms to load, so it's not clear why this is even an issue?)

Comment: this is of course a big issue, not only for performance, but: ILM will create many things such as index, templates ... monitoring as well. We use elasticsearch sometimes only for ... search, and I see through releases it consumes more and more resources.